# Visual Studio: Why Does the Target Framework Setting Cause It to Forget References?

Tags: visual-studio, reference

I got bitten by something that seems like a really nasty bug in Visual Studio 2010 this morning. I had a reference to another assembly which VS would "forget" after every solution build. If I deleted the reference and then added it back the reference would be recognized...up until the next build.

I assumed it was some problem with my solution for way too long. After much hair-tearing I searched online and found the following link, which solved the problem: http://robfine.com/aspnet/ReferenceRemovedBuildVisualStudio2010, but I'm curious as to why a mismatch in the target framework setting would lead to this behavior. And, more importantly, how come it wasn't fixed in VS2010 SP1 :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a flaw, the IDE doesn't yell loud enough when you reference an assembly that can't work at runtime.  The issue is that this assembly has an indirect dependency on another framework assembly that is not available in the Client profile.  Typically that's system.web.dll.

It normally puts up a warning icon on the assembly reference.  That's very easy to miss though, you'd have to have the References node expanded.  And there are enough programmers that have been bitten by it to give some credence to VS2010 simply failing to put up this icon.  I'm guessing this happens when a type from such an assembly isn't used in any publicly visible class method or property.  The compile error is indeed miserable.

The whole thing is a bit of a shambles, the client profile install is only 15% smaller than the full version.  Having one for 4.0 in the first place was a mistake.  And yes, nothing was changed in SP1 afaik.

Well, that's why Q+A sites like SO exist.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm understanding correctly, you problem might be because you're referencing a dll that targets a newer version of the .NET framework than your project. if you have a .NET 3.0 project, you can only reference assemblies built to target .NET 3.0 and less. you can't reference those that target 3.5 or 4.0.

Maybe you can elaborate more on the question so that the problem would be pinpointed more precisely.

Hope this helps